# Getting an error while trying to drop rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
fin_data[fin_data['Ticker']=='DNMR']

            high        low        open        close       volume   adj_close   Ticker  CUMLOGRET_1 PCTRET_1    CUMPCTRET_1 OBV EMA_5   EMA_10  EMA_20  VWMA_15 BBL_20_2.0  BBM_20_2.0  BBU_20_2.0  RSI_14  PVT MACD_10_20_9    MACDh_10_20_9   MACDs_10_20_9   VOLUME_SMA_10   NAV Status  Premium_over_NAV
date                                                                                                            
2020-05-28  4.700000    4.700000    4.700000    4.700000    100.0   4.700000    DNMR    NaN NaN NaN 100.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  Completed   -0.530
2020-05-29  4.700000    4.700000    4.700000    4.700000    0.0     4.700000    DNMR    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    100.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.000000e+00    NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  Completed   -0.530
2020-06-01  9.660000    9.630000    9.630000    9.660000    2000.0  9.660000    DNMR    0.720431    1.055319    1.055319    2100.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 100.000000  2.110638e+05    NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  Completed   -0.034
2020-06-02  9.660000    9.650000    9.650000    9.660000    60020   9.660000    DNMR    0.720431    0.000000    1.055319    2100.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 100.000000  2.110638e+05    NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  Completed   -0.034
2020-06-03  9.720000    9.630000    9.720000    9.630000    1100.0  9.630000    DNMR    0.717321    -0.003106   1.052214    1000.0  7.670000    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 99.303423   2.107222e+05    NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  Completed   -0.037
```

I'd like to either drop the first two rows where the close price is 4.70 or replace 4.70 by 9.66.

In order to drop the rows I tried this but it's giving me an error:

```
fin_data.drop(fin_data[fin_data['Ticker']=='DNMR'],axis=0,inplace=True)
KeyError: "['high' 'low' 'open' 'close' 'volume' 'adj_close' 'Ticker' 'CUMLOGRET_1'\n 'PCTRET_1' 'CUMPCTRET_1' 'OBV' 'EMA_5' 'EMA_10' 'EMA_20' 'VWMA_15'\n 'BBL_20_2.0' 'BBM_20_2.0' 'BBU_20_2.0' 'RSI_14' 'PVT' 'MACD_10_20_9'\n 'MACDh_10_20_9' 'MACDs_10_20_9' 'VOLUME_SMA_10' 'NAV' 'Status'\n 'Premium_over_NAV'] not found in axis"
```

Then I tried replace the 4.70 values but even though the code executed without an error the DataFrame is unchanged.

```
fin_data.loc[fin_data['Ticker']=='DNMR','adj_close'][0:2] = 9.66
```

Please note that I don't want to delete the data for those two dates (2020-05-28 and 2020-5-29) for other Tickers in the database but just for this one ('DNMR')

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't a simple `fin_data[(fin_data['Ticker'] != 'DNMR']) | (fin_data['close'] != 4.7)]` sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

you are using it wrong, to drop the rows in question (or actually select the opposite ones) you should do

```
fin_data = fin_data[(find_data['Ticker'] == 'DNMR']) & (fin_data['close'] == 4.7)]
```

Comment: Thanks, Jimmar. I guess it should be !=4.7 instead of ==4.7. I tried this solution but those two rows remain in the new data frame.

Answer (score 0):

to point out something about your drop-issue:

the drop() method expects "single label or list-like Index or column labels to drop" ([DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)) so this would work (notice the .index after the subset)

```
df
    a   b  c   d
0  10   8  3   5
1   5   5  3   1
2   2   2  8   6

df.drop(df[df["a"]== 10].index, axis= 0, inplace= True)
df
   a   b  c   d
1  5   5  3   1
2  2   2  8   6
```

BUT, if you have dates as indexes and there are multiple rows with the same dates, you would also drop those.

A solution would be to reset the index to integers.. but (even though I don't see why you would want non-unique indexes) that may not be what you want and you should stick to Jimmar's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite often simpler to use a mask

- values updates
- rows dropped

```
import pandas as pd
import io
fin_data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""date            high        low        open        close       volume   adj_close   Ticker  CUMLOGRET_1 PCTRET_1    CUMPCTRET_1 OBV EMA_5   EMA_10  EMA_20  VWMA_15 BBL_20_2.0  BBM_20_2.0  BBU_20_2.0  RSI_14  PVT MACD_10_20_9    MACDh_10_20_9   MACDs_10_20_9   VOLUME_SMA_10   NAV Status  Premium_over_NAV
                                                                                                            
2020-05-28  4.700000    4.700000    4.700000    4.700000    100.0   4.700000    DNMR    NaN NaN NaN 100.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  Completed   -0.530
2020-05-29  4.700000    4.700000    4.700000    4.700000    0.0     4.700000    DNMR    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    100.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.000000e+00    NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  Completed   -0.530
2020-06-01  9.660000    9.630000    9.630000    9.660000    2000.0  9.660000    DNMR    0.720431    1.055319    1.055319    2100.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 100.000000  2.110638e+05    NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  Completed   -0.034
2020-06-02  9.660000    9.650000    9.650000    9.660000    60020   9.660000    DNMR    0.720431    0.000000    1.055319    2100.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 100.000000  2.110638e+05    NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  Completed   -0.034
2020-06-03  9.720000    9.630000    9.720000    9.630000    1100.0  9.630000    DNMR    0.717321    -0.003106   1.052214    1000.0  7.670000    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 99.303423   2.107222e+05    NaN NaN NaN NaN 10  Completed   -0.037"""), sep="\s+")

fin_data.date=pd.to_datetime(fin_data.date)
fin_data = fin_data.set_index(["date"])

mask = fin_data["Ticker"].eq("DNMR") & fin_data["close"].eq(4.7)
fin_data.loc[mask, "close"] = 0
print(fin_data.iloc[:,0:6].to_markdown())
```

| date | high | low | open | close | volume | adj_close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-28 00:00:00 | 4.7 | 4.7 | 4.7 | 0 | 100 | 4.7 |
| 2020-05-29 00:00:00 | 4.7 | 4.7 | 4.7 | 0 | 0 | 4.7 |
| 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | 9.66 | 9.63 | 9.63 | 9.66 | 2000 | 9.66 |
| 2020-06-02 00:00:00 | 9.66 | 9.65 | 9.65 | 9.66 | 60020 | 9.66 |
| 2020-06-03 00:00:00 | 9.72 | 9.63 | 9.72 | 9.63 | 1100 | 9.63 |

```
fin_data = fin_data.drop(fin_data.loc[mask].index, axis=0)
print(fin_data.iloc[:,0:6].to_markdown())
```

| date | high | low | open | close | volume | adj_close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | 9.66 | 9.63 | 9.63 | 9.66 | 2000 | 9.66 |
| 2020-06-02 00:00:00 | 9.66 | 9.65 | 9.65 | 9.66 | 60020 | 9.66 |
| 2020-06-03 00:00:00 | 9.72 | 9.63 | 9.72 | 9.63 | 1100 | 9.63 |

Comment: Thanks, Rob. Would your rows drop function also delete other rows in the database with the same date?

Comment: no - look at the mask,  it's the ticker and the value of close

Comment: I run the exact same code as you and the mask is not capturing those two rows. The mask results in a series of only False booleans. I don't understand why because your code makes perfect sense and as you have demonstrated it works. Could there be something in my pandas version? Or the way my index, columns are structured?

Comment: that's exactly what a mask is...  True/False against an index for inclusions/exclusions

Comment: I mean that the mask is not capturing the first two rows as True and all else as False.